# Обернуть определнное слово в тег

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеем на странице блоки с разными словосочетаниями. Например:

```
<div class="title">Название 1.5-размер</div>
<div class="title">Название 2-размер</div>
<div class="title">Название евро</div>
<div class="title">Название2 2-размер</div>
<div class="title">Название2 1.5-размер</div>
и т.д.
```

Необходимо обернуть в `<span>` постоянные значения "1.5-размер", "2-размер" и "евро". Чтоб изменялись названия, а размерность в списке была выделена.

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос? какие проблемы возникли при решении? строки для замены могут быть только такие: _"1.5-размер", "2-размер" и "евро"._? и никаких других или возможны варианты?

Comment: Может быть еще парочка вариантов. Но в общем-то да, есть разные названия и в названии текстовым окончанием является одно из этих 3х вариантов. То есть, эти значения постоянные

Comment: что с ответами на остальные вопросы?

Comment: И еще этот текст должен выделяться только в одном месте на странице? В данном случае, **только** в div'e с классом _title_? или вообще везде на странице?

Comment: Не хватает опыта, для описания условия. Если бы нужно было заменить или обернуть целиком содержимое блока, то через .replaceWith это можно без труда реализовать. А вот выделить конкретную фразу не выходит. Выделяться должен только в конкретном блоке с привязкой к классу.

Comment: Тоесть есть только 3 значения, которые можно и нужно обернуть. Никаких других нет?

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин, выше в комментариях: _Может быть еще парочка вариантов._

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - составить regex. Проверить можно на http://regexr.com/ и подобных сервисах. Возможно, придется часть кода переписать под браузеры постарее, прости, привык писать под babel.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach((el) => {

  let html = el.innerHTML;

  html = html.replace(/(1\.5-размер|2-размер|евро)/, (full, a1) => {
    return `<span>${a1}</span>`
  });

  el.innerHTML = html;
})
```

```css
.title {
  width: 100%;
}
span {
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Название 1.5-размер</div>
<div class="title">Название 2-размер</div>
<div class="title">Название евро</div>
<div class="title">Название2 2-размер</div>
<div class="title">Название2 1.5-размер</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, простое и понятное решение. Правда очень современное)

Answer (score 2):

Пока оставлю 2 варианта, которые сам накопал. Если кто-то предложит более простой вариант, буду рад.

Если нужно выделать одно слово:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".title").html(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(new RegExp("евро", 'g'), "<span>евро</span>")
        });
    });
```

```css
span {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">Текст евро</div>
```

Для моих задач идеальным вариантом стал [этот](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) скрипт. Так как с его помощью можно достаточно легко сделать выделение в разных частях сайта с разными классами.

```js
$('.title').highlight('1.5-размер');
$('.title').highlight('евро');
```

```css
span {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-5.js"></script>
<div class="title">Название 1.5-размер</div>
<div class="title">Название евро</div>
```

Comment: Если используешь jquery в проекте нужно сразу ставить тег jquery в вопросе.

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин, я уже добавил

Comment: Да, простите. Протупил с этим моментом.

Answer (score 1):

Такая вот нехитренькая функция. Работает локально, не идеал, но суть передает.

```
function wrap(string, search_strings){ //string - строка В которой осуществляется поиск
    //search_strings - массив строк ДЛЯ поиска в строке string
    var k = search_strings.length;
    while(k--){
        var re = new RegExp('(?:\\s|^)' + search_strings[k] + '(?=\\s|$)','g');
        //Создаем регулярку на каждый элемент из массива со строками для поиска
        //Она ищет установленную строку, если перед ней *Пробел или Начало строки*
        //и после нее *Пробел, либо Конец строки*
        string = string.replace(re,' <span>' + search_strings[k] + '</span>');
        //Находим и заменяем их на них же, обрамленными в теги. Для остроты, можно
        //тег вынести в переменную в аргумент функции
    }
    return string;
}
wrap('Hello this is a test. Go learn some js',['is','js']);
//"Hello this <span>is</span> a test. Go learn some <span>js</span>"
```

Цепляешь к строчке нужного HTML, найденого из jQ, или там JS, не суть. При желании пилится в расширение прототипа для вида `String.wrap(search_strings,tag)`

Comment: Спасибо, решение интересное. Возьму на заметку!